Passing the filter I want to PowerBi Embed <PowerBiEmbed /> in React Typescript
I am working on passing a filter that must pass to the powerbi on load of the report. I am using react typescript with <PowerBiEmbed /> is it possible to pass the value I put to filter the content of powerbiembed onload of the report?
I tried making a filter like this:
const filter: models.IBasicFilter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    filterType: models.FilterType.Basic,
    target: {
        table: "SampleTable",
        column: "[Column1]"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: [12345]
};

and then on my PowerBIEmbed looks like this:
<PowerBIEmbed
    embedConfig={{
        type: 'report',
        id: 'id', // Replace with your report ID
        embedUrl: 'url', // Replace with your report's embed URL
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken, // Replace with your access token
        filters: [filter],
        settings: {
            panes: {
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: false
                },
                filters: {
                    expanded: false,
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        }
    }}
    eventHandlers={
        new Map([
            ['loaded', function () { console.log('Report loaded'); }],
            ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }]
        ])
    }
/>

I am expecting to load the report with the filter i passed on <PowerBiEmbed>.

I figured it out, I have the wrong value of filter thats why it does not load the report I want. to handle this correctly you must check this changes:
const filter: models.IBasicFilter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    filterType: models.FilterType.Basic,
    target: {
        table: "SampleTable",
        column: "Column1"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: ["12345"]
};

the problem is that column should not be enclosed in [] and also check the data type of that column in my case, i tried passing number to filter but i changed it to string and it now loads the report with the filter i want to see. Thats it.
